# Mongoose - Update/Find Specific Object in an Array Not Working As Expected

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am following the docs without luck and am at a standstill while trying to update an object in an object in an array using MongoDB and Mongoose.

Here is my document:

```
{
   fields: [
     { id: 603d63086db2db00ab09f50f, data: [Object] },
     { id: 603d63086db2db00ab09f510, data: [Object] },
     { id: 603d63086db2db00ab09f511, data: [Object] },
     { id: 603d63086db2db00ab09f512, data: [Object] },
     { id: 603d63086db2db00ab09f513, data: [Object] },
     { id: 603d63086db2db00ab09f514, data: [Object] },
     { id: 603d63086db2db00ab09f515, data: [Object] }
   ],
   layouts: [],
   _id: 603d631a6db2db00ab09f517,
   bandId: '603d63146db2db00ab09f516',
   eventType: 'private',
   ownerId: '6039354906410800c14934c1',
   __v: 0
 }
```

I am trying to `updateOne` of the `fields.data` in the `fields` array. `fields.data` is an object as well.

I call my Express/Node Backend to this route.

```
//Update
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let updating = await QuoteGenerator.updateOne(
      { _id: req.params.id, "fields.id": req.body.id },
      {
        "$set": {
          "fields.$.data": req.body.data,
        },
      }
    );
    let item = await QuoteGenerator.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
    res.json({ success: "Item Updated.", item });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.json({ error: "Something went wrong when updating this item." });
  }
});
```

Where `req.body` is:

```
{ id: '603d63086db2db00ab09f50f', data: { type: 1, rate: '200.30' } }
```

**Just in case it's helpful, here is what one of the `fields` objects looks like in the document,

```
{"id":"603d63086db2db00ab09f50f","data":{"type":1,"rate":300}}
```

I have even tried changing my route to find this document - which I have confirmed exists - Truly at a loss why it won't find the document.

Here is how I changed the above route to find the document.

```
//Update
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let updating = await QuoteGenerator.find(
      { _id: req.params.id, "fields.id": req.body.id },
    );
    console.log(updating) //returns []
    let item = await QuoteGenerator.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
    res.json({ success: "Item Updated.", item });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.json({ error: "Something went wrong when updating this item." });
  }
});
```

The Model

```
//Create Schema - QG
const QuoteGeneratorSchema = new Schema({
  bandId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  ownerId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  fields: {
    type: Array,
    default: defaultFields,
    required: true,
  },
  eventType: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  layouts: {
    type: Array,
    required: false,
  },
});

let QuoteGenerator = mongoose.model("QuoteGenerator", QuoteGeneratorSchema);

module.exports = QuoteGenerator;
```

Any nudge in the right direction to replacing that `data` object with a new `data` object would be extremely helpful! Thanks!

Comment: "603d63086db2db00ab09f50f" looks a lot like an ObjectId - if it is not a string you will need to cast it to the right type when querying

Comment: Hmm... I believe it is a string when I send it from the front end. I am going to double check though because I am still stuck with this problem! Thanks so much for the response. The only other thing I can think of, is that it may be the model that prevents this from finding that object? I'll add the model to the question above, in case you are keen to this.